# Problems with the formatting

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Write a program that requires users to enter integers, each in a separate line. The user indicates the end of the entry in a blank line. The program prints negated values. The program prints values ​​in the same line separated by a space.

```
n = input()
while n != "":
    n = int(n)
    print(-n, end=" ")
    n = input()
print(-n, end=" ")
```

This code works, but it needs help with the formatting.
The input should look like this:

- 5
- 0
- -11
- 2. 

The output should look like this:
-5 0 11 -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to input all values *first* and then print you need save them all to a list. Then, print them out after you're doing inputting. You can do this by using `join()`, but note that you must convert from `str` to `int` and back to `str` with this.

```
all_nums = []
n = input()
while n != "":
    all_nums.append(str(-int(i)))
    n = input()
print(" ".join(all_nums))
```

Instead, if you would like to print the numbers out with a normal loop you can do this

```
all_nums = []
n = input()
while n != "":
    all_nums.append(-int(i))
    n = input()
for i in all_nums:
    print(i, end=" ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! We still didn't study about lists in school so I didn't know I had to solve it with lists.